# How to apply JDK 6 patch to JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, patch

I have JBoss 4.2.0GA which primarily does not support JDK 6. I found [JBossWithJDK6 Patch](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWithJDK6). How can I apply this patch. I have ant installed in Ubuntu. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a diff tool to apply the patch (open it in a text editor to see the details).
You'll need to download the JBoss source, apply the patch and compile your own version of JBoss. It's probably *a lot* easier to just install JDK5. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

RedHat do not officially support Java6 with JBossAS 4.2.x, but that doesn't mean it doesn't work - it actually works fine.  The patch you mentioned is to allow you to build JBoss from source against Java6, you shouldn't need it just to run it.